# Running script when FreeBSD boots, but changing cwd first

Tags: freebsd

I want to run a script when FreeBSD boots. I tried symlinking to it from /usr/local/etc/rc.d, but the script itself (`myscript.sh`) uses paths such as `./init-site.sh`. These don't resolve correctly when invoked from /usr/local/etc/rc.d.

What would a simple script look like that would start `myscript.sh` and allow it's use of dot characters to correctly resolve to the script's own directory rather than /usr/local/etc/rc.d?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cd /actual/path/to/script
```

On top of your script?

Or you could add your script to `/etc/rc.local`. That way the script will run form it's current location and you would not have to worry about the path.

`/etc/rc.conf` is normally a file that contains loads of variables, but you can call commands to run at runtime also. Just add your script at the bottom.

```
 ./actual/path/to/script/myscript.sh
```

More info: [FreeBSD Handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/configtuning-core-configuration.html)

Comment: hmm... i can't edit the target script unfortunately. Is there an easy way to create a wrapper?

Comment: Edited my post.

Comment: I tried symlinking to the script from `/usr/local/etc/rc.d` but it can't resolve paths in `./xxx` format. I can't copy the script into `/usr/local/etc/rc.d` or the same thing will happen.

Comment: Sorry, brainfart... Edit above

Comment: NEVER, I repeat, NEVER add  script calls to `rc.conf`. This file is sourced many times during boot process and any operations with rc-scripts. There is old `/etc/rc.local` file for commands which need to be executed during boot (which is sourced by `/etc/rc.d/local`). Check `rcorder /etc/rc.d/*` to ensure that it called at the right time.